# Simple letter subs with a twist!

Tags: cipher, letters

**Here's your typical letter substitution puzzle that you can solve, no tricks.**
***But even so, there's a twist! Decipher this and find out the hidden message!***

---

xhtm tm ytxeanyyq nofxhea wdccye mf jerfje xhtm jrgh bipiy ibwh cshj wioxwi jrgh npts ad outybar rdk xtppda qbp

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that:

> there are three separate substitution ciphers going on.
>  The first third of the message spells `this is literally another puzzle so decode this`; the second spells `this never ends just decode this`; the last spells `snap to reality you cannot win`. Each is encoded independently, with a separate cipher.